# How to execute rest api from java and capture the response?

Tags: java, xml, rest

Executing this url on my browser: http://localhost:3161/devices/simulator/stop

I don't need login for it. It returns this rest api xml:

```
<response>
    <type>response</type>
    <ts>1463749194000</ts>
    <status>OK</status>
    <msg-version>2.3.0</msg-version>
    <op>stop</op>
    <data/>
</response>
```

How can I execute this from JAVA and then capture the xml response?

Comment: have you done any research at all? this is a very common scenario

Comment: yes I done it, can you help me? @andrew.butkus

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned in this post, it is generic thing, you would be able to find it online already..

I know there are clients to call the REST services from Java. Two of them are listed for your case.

case -1 : if you are using Jersey REST API. Here to capture XML , you can go with your own way,for example use JAXB and XML elements to Java Bean properties.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
  Client client = Client.create(config);
  WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri('http://localhost:3161/devices/simulator/stop').build());
  // getting XML data
  System.out.println(service. path('restPath').path('resourcePath').accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
  // getting JSON data
  System.out.println(service. path('restPath').path('resourcePath').accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class));
 }
}
```

Case 2: using HTTP method, it is simple method but parse XML instead of printing it here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet('http://localhost:3161/devices/simulator/stop');
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  String line = '';
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You welcome.  Please  acxept my answer if it helps with  any edits if required. Thx